# Multiline label aligment in wxButton

Tags: linux, wxwidgets

When I assign a multiline label to a wxButton, on MS Windows I get this result:

```
|    xxxxxxxx    |
|      yyyy      |
```

But on Linux, the same code results in:

```
|    xxxxxxxx    |
|    yyyy        |
```

I'd like to have the MS Windows behaviour on Linux too.

Filling the text with space characters is not a solution, for me.

How can I solve this problem?